# analytic continuation for $(e^z)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

We have the function $(e^z)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Choose a branch that is analytic in the circle $|z-2| <1$. Then analytically continue this branch over the curve $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ a curve going from $z=2$ around origin counter-clockwise in a loop back to $z=2$. Do the new functional values agree with the old ones?

So i did this already for the function $3z^{\frac{2}{3}}$, all i did was to rewrite it in exponential form and then going around the loop once will add some radians to the argument making the functional values not to agree.

How do i do it for this exponential function? Im not even sure how to define a branch for this, any hints?

Comment: How would you do it if we re-scaled the problem ; with the function $e^w$ and the circle $|3w-2| < 1$, or $|w-2/3| < 1/3$?

Comment: For me that is just the same problem with different numbers, the problem is to define a branch to start with, not sure how to do that? Can I rewrite $e^w$ to $e^{u+iv}=e^u(cosv+isinv)$ and then let v vary from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ ?

Comment: A branch cut is a curve such that when the complex plane is considered without this curve, the restriction of your function to that domain is analytic. 

What if the function is *already* analytic?

Comment: I think the part that confuses me is that they tell me to chose a branch and then analytically continue it over a curve. I simply don't understand what they want me to do with the given function? It is, as you say, already analytic everywhere. 

When i did it with the other function it was easier, I choose the principal branch $-\pi<Argz≤\pi$ and then did the continuation from $\pi$ on forward to $2\pi$, this is correct right? I mean I haven't fully misunderstood the exercise?

Comment: When you choose branches around a branch point it's because you are turning around a singularity of the function and you try to cut off separate values that the multi-valued function could take. If the function can only take one value, cutting off branches is just going to make the domain smaller and analytic continuation will just give you those values back again.

Comment: Yeah okay, but I still don't know how to do it for this function. :(

Comment: the point is that you're confused because there's nothing to do. In the case of $z^{1/2}$ for instance, you make a cut from $0$ to $\infty$ in some direction and re-write
$$
z^{1/2} = e^{\frac 12 \log z}
$$
and then choose a branch of $\log$ to define the branch for your function. The point of this construction is that $z^{1/2}$ is *not initially well-defined* unless you make a choice to begin with, which is what choosing a branch means, because there are two branches. If there is only one branch, you have no choice to make at all!

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying and the answer to the question is then that the new function values agree with the old ones when you go around the loop, but how do I state that more mathematically? How would you write it down as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The analytic continuation theorem states that two holomorphic functions on a domain which agree on an open subset of that domain are equal. (The statement can be made stronger but we don't need more.)

Therefore any function $f$ which is holomorphic on your disk and satisfies $f(z)^3 = e^z$ is actually equal to $e^{z/3}$ on all of $\mathbb C$ (see Edit : or a third root of unity multiple of it) since the latter is holomorphic on all of $\mathbb C$.

EDIT : As was obviously pointed out, I mistook $e^{z/3}$ for $(e^z)^{1/3}$.  The point is extracting the third root last involves a choice of branch for $g(w) = w^{1/3}$. Choose a branch for that function and then compose it with $e^z$ ; you should obtain either of $e^{(z+2*k*\pi)/3}$ for $k=0,1,2$, which are three distinct branches that are analytic over all of $\mathbb C$ and agree nowhere ; note that $e^z \neq 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$, which is the branch point of $g$ ; this explains why the branches are holomorphic everywhere.

Hope that helps,

Comment: $e^{z/3}$ or $e^{(z+2i\pi)/3}$ or $e^{(z+4i\pi)/3}$

Comment: @mercio : Okay, I feel stupid. But thanks!